# How to define conversions between templates meant to represent 2D coordinates?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I have an application where for some reason (well, speed and storage space, basically) I need to work with integer 2D coordinates *most* of the time.

Some intermediate computations require floating point, though.

I defined a template to implement the same operations on integer- and double-valued coordinates like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct tTypedPoint {
    T x, y;

    tTypedPoint() {}
    tTypedPoint(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    tTypedPoint(const tTypedPoint & p) { *this = p; }
    tTypedPoint operator+ (const tTypedPoint & p) const { return{ x + p.x, y + p.y }; }
    tTypedPoint operator- (const tTypedPoint & p) const { return{ x - p.x, y - p.y }; }
    tTypedPoint operator* (T scalar) const { return{ x * scalar, y * scalar }; }
    tTypedPoint operator/ (T scalar) const { return{ x / scalar, y / scalar }; }
    bool operator== (const tTypedPoint & p) const { return x == p.x && y == p.y; }
    T dot(const tTypedPoint &p) const { return x*p.x + y * p.y; } // dot product  
};

typedef short  tCoord;
typedef double tFloatCoord;

typedef tTypedPoint<tCoord     > tPoint;
typedef tTypedPoint<tFloatCoord> tFloatPoint;
```

As it is, I cannot mix `tPoint` and `tFloatPoint` operations without copying `tPoints` into `tFloatPoints` explicitely, which is both ugly and inefficient.

Ideally, I would like a `tPoint` to be converted into a `tFloatPoint` in a manner similar to base types promotion (like an `int` is promoted to `double`, for instance).

Frankly I have no clue how to do this, if that is even possible.
I have looked into the conversion operators but I can't see how I could define them in that case (you would have to specify the type of the converted point somewhere, but I can't see where).

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious there, but my brain simply fails to process this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a template constructor:

```
template <typename T>
struct tTypedPoint {
    T x, y;

    template<typename U>
    tTypedPoint(const tTypedPoint<U>& rhs) : x(rhs.x), y(rhs.y) {}

    // Previous code
};
```

You may also restrict this constructor with SFINAE or `static_assert` to make sure that the conversion is what you want to allow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I *knew* it was obvious after all :).